# Git bundle remove branch

Tags: git

I'm making a backup script for a git repo.
I have stumbled upon this problem, and I can't think of a solution.

The script makes a full backup every week, and a incremetal every day : `--since=1.days`.
It uses git bundle to process the history.

The problem arises when there was a branch when a full backup was done, and later removed when an incremetal was done.

Since git bundle, only stores the changes, there is no information about other references.
Adding a new branch is fairly simple, since it involves checking if an incremetal bundle has a new reference, that was not in the full backup bundle.

Is there a way to store information about removed references in the bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround I did was have a separate file that contained only the references that where present while doing the incremental backup. That way, when the repository had a reference that was not in the incremental that I am applying, the reference was removed.